# How can I replace the contents of one List<int> with those from another?

Tags: c#, winforms, arraylist, nullable

I was using two nullable int[]s:

```
int?[] OriginalPterodactylVals = new int?[NUMBER_OF_BABES_IN_TOYLAND];
int?[] ChangedPterodactylVals = new int?[NUMBER_OF_BABES_IN_TOYLAND];
```

...and this code to sync them up:

```
ChangedPterodactylVals.CopyTo(OriginalPterodactylVals, 0);
```

...but now I've changed the int[]s to Lists and haven't yet found or figured out how to accomplish the same thing.

They will both have the same amount of values in the list at the time one is "copied and pasted" into the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
OriginalPterodactylVals.Clear();
ChangedPterodactylVals.ForEach(val => { OriginalPterodactylVal.Add(val); });
```

Comment: The constructor `List<T>(IEnumerable<T>)` accomplishes a similar goal, though it creates a new list rather than clearing an repopulating the original list.  There would only be a difference if a reference was already being held to the original list.

Comment: Just pointing out the similarities and differences.  If something already holds a reference to `OriginalPterodactylVals`, and the desire is for the list pointed-to to update, your solution is the correct one.

Comment: I marked this as the answer, but to be nitpicky "foreach" needs to be "ForEach" and ".add" needs to be ".Add"

Comment: yeah - sorry about that - been jumping between languages and frameworks a bit.

Answer (score 9):

You can perform a shallow copy by constructing a new list from your existing list:

```
list2 = new List<int>(list1);
```

Note that this creates a *new* list rather than modifying the list that `list2` originally refered to (if any).

Here is an approach that modifies the existing list using [`AddRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) rather than creating a new one:

```
list2.Clear();
list2.AddRange(list1);
```

And here's another approach using a `for` loop. This requires that the lists have the same length, but you stated that this is the case in your question.

```
for (int i = 0; i < list1.Count; ++i)
{
    list2[i] = list1[i];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to initialize a new List from an existing List,

```
List<int> a;
List<int> b = new List<int>(a);
```

That approach leverages the `List<T>` constructor that accepts an `IEnumerable<T>`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0.aspx

Note using that constructor, you can also initialize a list from an array

```
int[] a = new int[42];
List<int> b = new List<int>(a);
```

Comment: Okay, but these are existing lists; I don't want to create a new one...Would this work:
OriginalPterodactylVals = ChangedPterodactylVals ?

Comment: That would assign the reference `ChangedPterodactylVals` to the variable `OriginalPterodactylVals`, creating an alias.  Both variables would point to the same list.  Change one list, and the thing pointed to by both variables changes.